# C#: Why is this code ignored?

Tags: c#, winforms

Sorry about the weird question title, but I don't really know what to call this. It simply makes no sense to me. Here is the code:

```
public partial class ParameterPanel : FlowLayoutPanel
{
    ...

    public void SetContents(IEnumerable<IParameter> parameters)
    {
        if (parameters == null || !parameters.Any())
            return;

        SuspendLayout();
        Controls.Clear();

        foreach (IParameter parameter in parameters)
        {
            Control control = Factory.Create(parameter);
            Controls.Add(control);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("???");

        ResumeLayout(false);
        PerformLayout();
    }
}
```

The weird thing is that the code sometimes never gets to the `Console.WriteLine` I break in the beginning of the method and try to step through it. It goes into the foreach loop, but after the last item, the method just returns?? It never reaches the `Console.WriteLine`. And I just don't get it... How is this even possible? And the weirdest thing is that it doesn't happen always either. But it happens consistently in the cases it does.

Anyone have a clue what is going on here? I don't even know where to start looking for this bug.

Comment: Is Controls.Add() failing at that point perhaps?

Comment: I assume an exception kicks you out of the method...

Comment: Ah, grr, found it. It was a NullReferenceException that happend in the constructor of one of the controls that were created by the factory. The thing that threw me off was that the exception didn't crash anything. It just... happend and was ignored, apparently. Noticed it in the output console. Had to turn on the Break thing for that exception in the Debug -> Exceptions... menu. Oh well... *sigh*

Comment: @Daniel, yeah you are right. But I don't understand why it was simply ignored. I can find no try-catch block that catch it. So I'm pretty sure that I don't swallow it anywhere. But someone did eat it...

Comment: I find that asking for help usually ensures that you find the solution yourself minutes later! :-)

Glad you sorted it.

Comment: @Ian, haha, yeah... hate it when that happens, but it happens a lot :p

Comment: If the calling thread is outside of application domain, then the default behavior is to silently swallowed the exception (if i remember correctly, it happens only when running the application from visual studio). I had the same problem with an exception thrown during a drag&drop of a file into my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If something in the method is throwing an exception the rest of the method will be skipped.

Hit Debug->Exceptions and tick the box for CLR exceptions to make VS break as soon as an exception is thrown.

Comment: Yeah, found it using that. But why didn't it break in the first place? All I got was "A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in TheApp.dll", and I don't understand where it got eaten.

Comment: Is something higher up catching the exception. I noticed you're inheriting from the FlowLayoutPanel; is set contents being caught from some overridden method that has a caller in FlowLayoutPanel that handles the exception? Try handling the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event to see if it's occurring on a background thread - although as this looks like GUI code I'm assuming it's not on a background thread.

Answer (score 1):

One oddity: if `parameters` is null or empty, you're never resuming or performing the layout... I know that's not the situation you're running into, but it's something to fix.

The other possibility is that an exception is being thrown somewhere in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Add check if control has been created successfully, if not then skip adding.

```
foreach (IParameter parameter in parameters)
{
    Control control = Factory.Create(parameter);
    if (control!=null) {
        Controls.Add(control);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be an exception occur in the foreach, try to check Debug->Exceptions-> Common language runtime exceptions, to see is there any exception or not

Answer (score 0):

As Jon Skeet says, the line -

```
if (parameters == null || !parameters.Any()) return;
```

is returning the function so in that case you'll never get any farther.  It's common to enforce this kind of contract at the beginning of a method but you'd usually throw an exception in this case.

Comment: Yeah, but in my case this wasn't the problem. The method did run past that. Anyways, the issue was caused by an exception that was thrown in the constructor of a control.